# C Segmentation Fault without any reason

Tags: arrays, struct, segmentation-fault

Can anyone please tell me why i have a segmentation fault here?

```
float element(float** mat,int k, int l, int block_size){
int i_start=k*block_size;
int i_end=(k+1)*block_size-1;
int j_start=l*block_size;
int j_end=(l+1)*block_size-1;
float somma=0;
int c=0;
float media=0;

for(;i_start<=i_end;i_start++){
    for(;j_start<=j_end;j_start++){
        somma+=mat[i_start][j_start];
        c++;
    }
}
media=somma/c;

return media;}



Mat* matrixScale(Mat* m, int block_size) {
Mat* new=(Mat*) malloc(sizeof(Mat));
new->rows=m->rows/block_size;
new->cols=m->cols/block_size;
new->row_ptrs=(float**) malloc(new->rows*sizeof(float*));
int i,j,z;
for(z=0;z<new->rows;z++)
    new->row_ptrs[z]=(float*) calloc(new->cols,sizeof(float));

for(i=0;i<m->rows;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m->cols;j++){
       new->row_ptrs[i][j]=elements(m->row_ptrs,i,j,block_size);
    }
}
return new;}
```

I tried using a debugger but it just says that the problem is inside the element function.

Comment: Tag you question with {c} to find more helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Your post needs more detail.  The line of the crash, the definition of Mat, what the intent is. etc.

For the future see how to make a [Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  You will get a quicker response with the 'C' tag as well.  Be sure to post a detailed question or you will get down voted and castigated.

There are multiple issues with the code.  The problem seems to around the block size variable.

```
int i_start=k*block_size;
int i_end=(k+1)*block_size-1;
int j_start=l*block_size;
int j_end=(l+1)*block_size-1;
```

Passing in a particular i,j combination and multiplying by block size will go past the end of the row_ptrs array.  Reading/writing past the end of the array is undefined and will result in a crash generally.  Perhaps you meant divide?

This bit is also odd.

```
for(i=0;i<m->rows;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m->cols;j++){
       new->row_ptrs[i][j]=elements(m->row_ptrs,i,j,block_size);
    }
}
```

The max index of rows is [m->rows/block_size][m->cols/block_size] but you are going all the way to [m-rows][m->cols].  Unless blocksize is 1 this will crash as it writes past the end of the array.